# How populate select box according to the selection of another select box item in cakephp 2.4

Tags: php, cakephp-2.4

I have two models. One is company and another is products.
I want to use these models as two separate select boxes. 1st one is company name and another is their products. If I selected company-1, then I need company-1's products in second select box only. How can I do this?

Comment: Sounds like something you'd do on the client in JS & not on the server in PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First retrieve all company list from in controller

```
 $this->Model->find(list);
```

and show this list in view..

And make another method in controller like

```
 find_product($id) 
 { 
     $this->Model->find('list',array('company_id'=>$id)));
 }
```

or fire ajax on company select list name change and call find_product and pass company id, and update product name with given response by find_product()...